# Can a HSDir see visited onion url's?

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing, deanonymization, hsdir

Is it possible that a HSDir can see visited onion urls? 
If I make a onion website and my friend visits it could there be a way that someone can capture the url he used? (the .onion url).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, currently HSDirs can see the looked up .onion hostname. This does not include the full URL but just the .onion hostname. [Proposal 224](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/proposals/224-rend-spec-ng.txt) (ticket [#12424](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/12424)) will fix this issue. See also [#8106](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/8106).

If you want to make the page accessible to your friends only the [`HiddenServiceAuthorizeClient`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#HiddenServiceAuthorizeClient) option might be something that could interest you.

Comment: Simply by logging with for instance tcpdump?

Comment: tcpdump won't work since it only sees encrypted traffic but it shouldn't be hard to modify Tor to log the addresses somewhere.